# How to write xml scripts for load testing "XMPP over BOSH" using Tsung?

Tags: xmpp, benchmarking, load-testing, tsung

I have to perform a comparison of "simple XMPP" with "XMPP over BOSH" for our mobile client(chat based). I want to use same tool to compare both. I searched on internet and found a tool called *tsung* which supports both HTTP and  XMPP. I have setup and able to run tsung for XMPP with given example scripts.

Now the problem is that I am unable to write Tsung xml scripts for "XMPP over BOSH". I tried searching on internet but couldn't find any.

Can somebody **please guide me in setting up Tsung for "XMPP over BOSH"**?

Please let me know if there exist a tool other than Tsung which can serve my purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From some time ago you can find BOSH support on TSUNG but only on their master branch in:

https://github.com/processone/tsung/blob/master/src/tsung/ts_bosh.erl

For enabling it in your script just change the type of connection to your servers to "bosh":

```
<server host="my_bosh_server" port="5280" type="bosh"></server>
```

Just make sure that your XMPP server is listening for BOSH connections on the "http-bind":

```
http://my_bosh_server:5280/http-bind
```

Alternatively you can use "bosh_ssl" instead of "bosh" if you want to add SSL to your connections. In any case, yes, it's completely undocumented.

Answer (score 3):

Tsung is a good choice to test XMPP.
And there is a jabber plugin of Tsung - this is a basic tool, just for basic XMPP like register, login, add contact/rename/delete, chat, MUC ,pubsub, presence(connected, online, offline ) ...

And also Tsung's jabber plugin supports raw XML - that means you can send any raw XML data to the server using the raw type :

> raw XML
>   You can send raw XML data to the server using the raw type:

```
<jabber type="raw" ack="no_ack" data="&lt;stream&gt;foo&lt;/stream&gt;"></jabber>
```

> Beware: you must encode XML characters like < ,>, &, etc.

For more content by http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual.html#htoc58

Comment: That's true. Tsung does not know BOSH .

Comment: Maybe you can try JMeter to test XMPP OVER BOSH ?